# Given sides of a right triangle, calculate one of its angles

Tags: trigonometry

I need help with this problem for trig:

> Given a right triangle with $c = 17.9$ and $a = 6.4$, find the measure of angle $\alpha$ in degrees, rounded to one decimal place. Draw a picture and show work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To be clear: How exactly are $c$, $a$, and $\alpha$ situated on the triangle? (It's *probably* intended that $c$ is the hypotenuse, and $\alpha$ the acute angle opposite leg $a$, but it's not wise to make these kinds of assumptions.)

Comment: Also, you should tell what you know about this problem, and where you got stuck, so that any answerers can tailor their responses properly. *Help us help you.*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $a$ is opposite $\alpha$ and $c$ is opposite the right angle:

$$\sin\alpha=\frac{6.4}{17.9}$$

$$\alpha=\arcsin\;\frac{6.4}{17.9}$$

I get ~$20.949^o$.